# Как избежать повторения передачи данных с контроллера в laravel

Tags: php, laravel

У меня в главном меню выводятся данные с модели (переданные через контроллер)

```
 @foreach($categories as $category)
                                    <li> <a href="#"</a>$category->title</li>
 @endforeach
```

Структура вообще такая, есть `файл content`, и он наследует главное меню (@extends "template")

И так как это выводится в главном меню, то есть вот эти данные должны везде быть переданы через контролер, чтобы не было `"undefined variable $categories"` . 
То есть я перехожу на другой url, и выдает ошибка (если конечно в этом контроллере не передал эти данные)

Подскажите, как гибко реализовать это, чтобы в каждом контроллере не приходилось передавать данные, а к примеру задали в одном, и уже не нужно больше повторений.
Пробовал через `@include`, делал проверку по роутам в итоге не получается.

Благодарю за помощь.

Comment: Ну в голову приходит пока такой вариант: Сделать это дело через посредника, он формирует массив для шаблонизатора (с вашими категориями), в контроллере вы его дописываете, и потом суммарное дело отправляете в блейд.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте использовать [View Composers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/views#view-composers) ([рус](https://laravel.ru/docs/v5/views#%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8)). Данный механизм позволяет получать данные непосредственно для конкретного шаблона перед его отрисовкой. То есть для каждого шаблона вы с помощью View Composers будете получать именно те данные, которые нужны и когда они нужны. Подробности реализации можно найти в указанных ссылках.